# How to create dock type toolbar at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

like in http://www.online-photoshoptutorials.com/2008/08/folding-corners.html

Comment: have a look at what they're using

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<div id="toolbar" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; color: #fff; background: #000;">
Toolbar Content 
<!-- rest of your toolbar stuff here -->
</div>
```

That will create a div with a black background that remains at the bottom of the screen, regardless of browser resizing or scrolling.  You can then style that div however you like.

Comment: And one more question,is this browser compactable>

Comment: @MatBridges I'm editing a SMF based site's css to have this effect on one of the div's, but when i do that all the other divs jump up, onto the div i just fixed, as if it wasn't part of the structure. Any suggestions to make everything run behind that div maintaining the intended layout?

Answer (score 2):

you use the css directive for positioning

```
position: fixed;
```

[more details and tinkering for the positioning](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)

Comment: Nope, i want to know how to create that from scratch

Comment: Oh well, that's a bit more complicated, and it's not something that can be answered. It would be like asking "how can I make a calendar widget ?"